# dbListConnections & MonetDB - which user is connected?

Tags: r, shiny-server, monetdb, r-dbi

I am using MonetDB with R thanks to the library MonetDB.R.

I do not seem to be able to use `dbListConnections`

I get:

```
> dbListConnections(dbDriver("MonetDB.R"))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListConnections’ for signature ‘"MonetDBDriver"’
```

Should I assume that `dbListConnections` is not implemented in MonetDB.R?

My challenge is to try to implement a multi-connection application using R and Shiny Server Pro: it would be useful to know which connections are established at a given time and with which user.

Are there alternative ways to establish which user is connected?

BTW, I've also tried to use the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.connections; -- * used for brevity, or

SELECT * FROM sys.sessions; -- * used for brevity
```

But both return NULL...

Comment: hi, `MonetDBLite` (on CRAN) now replaces `MonetDB.R` and runs embedded (like `RSQLite`).  for more detail, see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, `dbListConnections()` is not implemented. There is an easy way of finding out which user is connected, `SELECT current_user;`. `SELECT * FROM sessions;` should also work (or `dbReadTable(conn, "sessions")` in R .